# What is the function of 加以 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm certain  林俊宏 is an accomplished translator whose skill is far far beyond my puny attempts. I'm just wondering about this  加以。

Original English sentence from Sapiens, 人类简史:

In addition, since humans are born underdeveloped, they can be educated and socialised to a far greater extent than any other animal.

Original English sentence translated by 林俊宏  and back-translated by me.

此外，
In addition,
由于人类出生的时候尚未发育完全，
since humans are born underdeveloped,
比其他动物，
compared to other animals,
也就更能够用教育和社会化的方式加以改变。
they can be educated and socialised to a far greater extent.

加以：in addition, moreover
加以：can also function a bit like 把 to indicate 改变 applies to something previously mentioned (人类??)。

What is 加以 in this sentence??

Answer (score 1):

> 加 as a verb can mean: to add; to impose; to apply)

Example:

- 刀斧**加**身 = **apply** severe bodily harm or death (upon someone)
- 黃袍**加**身 = **impose** the imperial title (upon someone)

> 加以 = impose with / apply with

Example:

- **加以**起訴 = **impose with** indictment (= to indict)
- **加以**惩罚 = **impose with**/ **apply with** punishment (= to punish)
- **加以**改变 = **apply with** change (= to change)

> 也就更能够 - therefore, more able to

> 用教育和社会化的方式 - use the education and socialization method

> **加以**改变 - (to) **apply with** change (= to change it)

Comment: So, could I change this to: 也就更能够用教育和社会化的方式来改变人类动物。

Comment: @Pedroski If you meant "也就更能够用教育和社会化的方式来改变人类" ? the answer is  Yes, "改变人类" (change human)= 对人类加以改变 (apply change to human)